# How to catch softwareupdate output

Tags: macos, bash, terminal

I'm trying to catch the output of the softwareupdate command under OS X.
softwareupdate -l >> somefile does only catch the first few lines (Software Update Tool Copyright 2002-2012 Apple Inc. Finding available software), the rest is missing (No new software available.) I need it for a bash script.

Current catching code: 
    update=$(softwareupdate -l);

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try redirecting `stderr` messages as well. Command substitution only captures output sent to stdout (fd `1`; stderr = fd `2`).

```
update=$(softwareupdate -l 2>&1)
```